# checking is collection is empty on the razor view

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

in asp.net mvc app, my controller sends list of data to the view using viewdata.

On the view I iterate trough that collection and render some data

```
<ul class="nomargin">
  @foreach (var link in (List<MyDomain.UI.Controllers.SideLinks>)ViewData["Links1"])
  { 
    <li style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 15px;">
          <a href=@link.Link>@link.LinkName</a>
     </li>                               
  }
</ul>
```

Question is: how can I check if this collection ViewData["Links1"] is empty on the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the null-coalescing operator to make sure you always have a list (if there is the potential for your `ViewData` to be `null`)

```
<%
  var list = ViewData["Links1"] ?? new List<MyDomain.UI.Controllers.SideLinks>();
%>
```

Then you can always safely check `list.Count > 0` or `list.Any()` if you are using LINQ.

FYI you can add a `@using MyDomain.UI.Controllers` statement to your view so you don't need to use the fully qualified namespace to your class.

Comment: That would only work if `ViewData["Links1"] is null, not empty - it's not 100% clear from the question which he is after, so the question author may want to combine our answers!

Comment: @RB. Looks like I was too hasty with my answer it was only partially complete :) Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of your List.

```
@if ((List<MyDomain.UI.Controllers.SideLinks>)ViewData["Links1"]).Count == 0)
{
    <b>This is an empty list!</b>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldnt use `Count` property instead use `any`. Moreover, instead of using ViewBag, TempData or ViewData you should use strong typed objects.

If you still wanna do that, following would suffice:

```
@{ 
  var items = (List<MyDomain.UI.Controllers.SideLinks>)ViewData["Links1"];
 }

@if(items != null && items.any()){


   //rest of the stuff.
}
```

Comment: *"I wouldn't use Count property intead use `any`"* - well first of all, `List<T>` doesn't have an `any` property, there is a LINQ extension method called `Any()` which I presume you are referring to...Secondly, there is no performance benefit of using `Count/Any()` on a `List<T>`.